# MySQL: How to copy column from one table without id into another table?

Tags: mysql

Is possible to copy column 'hash' from TABLE2 into column 'hash' in TABLE1 ?

Thank you for help!
Kind regards,
Paul

```
TABLE 1
+----+--------+----------+
| id | name   | hash     |
+----+--------+----------+
| 21 | John   |          |
| 22 | Ann    |          |
| 23 | Peter  |          |
+----+--------+----------+

TABLE 2
+----------+
| hash     |
+----------+
| vfrtycfg |
| gtytghjg |
+----------+
```

I need to get this result:

```
+----+--------+----------+
| id | name   | hash     |
+----+--------+----------+
| 21 | John   | vfrtycfg |
| 22 | Ann    | gtytghjg |
| 23 | Peter  |          |
+----+--------+----------+
```

Comment: And if 'hash' has been copied, how the table 1 looks like? I mean, desired output.

Comment: How do you want to match the records? 
E.g. should `vfrtycfg` be assigned to John, Ann or Peter?

Comment: The table 2 has a random records in column 'hash'. It does not matter that the record will be copied from table 2 into table 1. We can copy the records one after another.

Comment: Can you have duplicates in table 1? There are only 2 hashes in table 2, but 3 records in table 1.

Comment: There are no duplicates in any of the tables

Comment: The question is still unclear. How did you know that vfrtycfg inserted into John row. What's the condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
JOIN (SELECT @rownum AS rownum, hash, @rownum := @rownum + 1
      FROM table2
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := MIN(id) FROM table1) AS var) AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.rownum
SET t1.hash = t2.hash
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02ab4/1)

The subquery adds a `rownum` column to `table2`, containing sequential IDs starting from the minimum ID in `table1`.